# function template specialization in a namespace

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, clang++

I want to specialize a function template. This function is declared in a namespace:

```
namespace foo
{
   template <int>
   void function();
}
```

(For simplicity, the template is based on an `int`, whereas in my production code, it is an `enum class`, but it is the same issue. The same goes for a type based template)

Now I want to specialize it for a specific value:

```
template <>
void foo::function<0>()
{
}
```

This fails to compile with `g++ -std=c++11` (versions 4.6, 4.7, 4.8 and 4.9):

> specialization of ‘template void foo::function()’ in different namespace [-fpermissive]

`clang++ -std=c++11` accepts this code.

g++ also accepts the following piece:

```
namespace foo
{
   template <>
   void function<0>()
   {
   }
}
```

Who's right, gcc or clang?

Comment: Both are right. The only difference is that clang has an extension that allows for this - nonstandard - declaration.

Comment: @Ethouris This contradicts Barrys answer. Care to point out where he's wrong?

Comment: No, it does not, although you might have misunderstood my answer. I said that both compilers are right, as they both say that this code does not conform to the standard C++. The only difference is that clang allows this **still nonstandard** code, but treats it as using a **nonstandard extension**.

Comment: That's my understanding of that section of the standard, but I am by no means an authority on the matter. I'm just a guy who answers questions on the Internet :-)

Comment: @Barry Sure, no doubt. But Ethouris is saying a different thing. So I'd like to encourage him to back up his statement with facts (such as quotes from a standard). One of you (or even both) is wrong, so I'd love to know who it is ;-)

Comment: @stefan I added some examples with my understanding of the rule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the standard, §14.7.3/2, emphasis mine:

> An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the specialized template. An explicit
>   specialization whose *declarator-id* is **not qualified** shall be declared in the nearest enclosing namespace of
>   the template, or, if the namespace is inline (7.3.1), any namespace from its enclosing namespace set.

You have to put `template<> function<0>();` in `namespace foo`. However, that rule only applies to an unqualified *declarator-id*. When you provide a *qualified-id* (as in `foo::function<0>`), I believe that clause should not apply, which makes clang correct here.

For example, given the `function` declared the question, I would expect the following:

```
namespace foo {
    template <> void function<0>(); // valid: unqualified explicit specialization
                                    // in the nearest enclosing namespace of the 
                                    // template
}

namespace bar {
    template <> void function<1>(); // invalid: unqualified explicit specialization
                                    // in the wrong namespace
}

struct baz {
    template <> void function<2>(); // invalid: unqualified explicit specialization
                                    // not in namespace scope
};

template <> void foo::function<3>(); // valid: qualified explicit specialization
                                     // is in a namespace, and id is qualified

template <> void bar::function<4>(); // invalid: there is no bar::function
                                     // to specialize
```

Comment: Global namespace encloses the specialized template, so how does the `template<> void foo::function<0>(){}` in global namespace breaks the rule you quoted?

Comment: @PowerGamer How is the global namespace by any means "the nearest enclosing namespace" for the `foo` namespace? Just asking - maybe you're right. This rules uses many quite unclear statements. It would be nice if I can see the difference between defining this thing in the "correct" and "wrong" namespace, as well as with "qualified" and "not qualified" declarator-id.

Comment: @Ethouris Added examples with what my understanding is of the rule.

Comment: @PowerGamer: But you haven't given any example of "explicit specialization whose declarator-id is not qualified". You simply state that if you are declaring an explicit specialization then the declarator-id is qualified. If so, this thing, mentioned in the standard, wouln't be able to exist!

Comment: @Ethouris Examples where there are no `foo::` before `function` are the examples where "declarator-id is not qualified".

Comment: @PowerGamer: The first sentence defines that it should be declared within the namespace where the template is defined. **Unless** this sentence is just a highly unclear version of "*An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace in which the template being specialized is defined, or any of its parent namespace, including global namespace, as long as the declaration uses qualified-id with the namespace path that leads to the template declaration being specialized*".

Comment: @Ethouris No it doesn't. The first sentence merely states that an explicit specialization be defined in a namespace: "An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the **specialized template.**" (as opposed to, say, inside of a class). It's only the 2nd sentence that talks about the original template, and only if it's not qualified.

Comment: @Barry: Good, but what does this **specialized template** mean in this sentence - the "master definition of the template for which the specialization is being considered" or "the specialization of the template"? If the first, then it's exactly as I wrote, if the second, this is a tautology.

Comment: @Ethouris Your rephrasing of the standard rule is much longer but correct. *specialized template* means *template being specialized* (which is not the same as *specialization of the template*). Qualified explicit specialization cannot be defined in ANY namespace, only in namespaces `enclosing the specialized template`. Lookup the definition of `enclosing namespace` in 7.3.1/6 in C++11 standard.

Comment: Good, thanks. Sorry for bothering, but it's good to have things clear.